# Photoshop - Transform content

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-cs5

I'm very new to photoshop.

I wanted to transform a layer like the one in the below snapshot.

[image]

The layer is not rotated, but the black background with your screenshot is here rotated.

I actually got this from a Macbook Air mock up where I wanted to fit in my screenshot and I'm actually unable to rotate and fit it exactly. I tried rotating the content using the Transform control but it didn't help.

Original mock up [here](http://graphicburger.com/macbook-air-mockup/).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either select the part you need to transform, then edit it. Or you can use distort, which is under edit > transform > distort.

Hope this helps. If you have a question, or if you don't understand something, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. Will accept the answer after the timer :)

Comment: No problem. Glad I was able to help